# Problems importing a CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv

When i try to import a CSV file into my mysql database I get this error "Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1".
But i am sure that my csv file is fine. Below is the first line of the csv file and the structure of the databse:

```
"","LDallolio@Panini.it","Licia Dallolio","390","37","","",

CREATE TABLE `other_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(256) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) default NULL,
  `opened` int(11) default NULL,
  `checked` int(11) default NULL,
  `category` varchar(256) default NULL,
  `company` varchar(256) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

If anyone can help me out with this I would be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try leaving out the first column, making it only 6 columns in your csv.

also, take the trailing comma off the end of the line

Comment: 6 columns (no identity column) and taking the trailing slash off should work, how are you importing it?

Comment: using mysql import. 
it did kinda work but it mised out the email address ad shifted everything left (so name became email etc)

Answer (score 1):

The trailing comma on the end of the csv line means there are actually 8 fields you are trying to import.